# High cpu usage of initAggregator method in AttributeAggregator

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

We are using siddhi-3.1.2 as our cep engine. We are currently using 1 thread to process all our data in siddhi. The data processing speed is very slow.

Profiling the cpu usage, we see that the majority of the time is spent in initAggregator method. Yourkit snapshot analysis shows that the CPU usage on a 1s sampling is about 954ms on this particular method.

```
Analytics (1/1)  TID=322  STATE=RUNNABLE  CPU_TIME=1978 (87.24%)  USER_TIME=1910 (84.20%) Allocted: 512423096
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.attribute.aggregator.AttributeAggregator.initAggregator(AttributeAggregator.java:47)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.attribute.processor.executor.GroupByAggregationAttributeExecutor.execute(GroupByAggregationAttributeExecutor.java:52)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.attribute.processor.AttributeProcessor.process(AttributeProcessor.java:38)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.processInBatchGroupBy(QuerySelector.java:225)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.selector.QuerySelector.process(QuerySelector.java:78)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.window.WindowProcessor.processEventChunk(WindowProcessor.java:57)
    org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.processor.stream.AbstractStreamProcessor.process(AbstractStreamProcessor.java:101)
```

The hot spot in the CPU is shown below.

[YourKitSnapshotImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phaAM.png)

I'm wondering if this time spent on initAggregator is expected in general or is that dependent on the siddhi query that is being processed.

Comment: It seems you are using "group by" within your query.. With that, it will create attribute aggregator per each group... So that might be the reason behind this... Therefore, can you please share the query that you are using to do the above testing?

Comment: Yes. Thats correct. We do have a group by on multiple fields in a stream. And the values of this field are dynamic. We found that our problem is https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/issues/431. The solution proposed in the issue has solved the slowness, with respect to cloning and copy on write array list. 

But it has exposed another problem that is discussed here, where AttributeAggregators for these dynamic groupBy values cause an OOM. - https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/issues/397

I guess a way to ensure AttributeAggregators can be evicted from the map safely is required.